# Order by showing bad results in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-order-by

In my query, I need to get the previous row with the current row and then join a few tables. I got the previous row by using SQL variables in my development server(MySQL 5.7), everything works fine, but in my production(MariaDB 10) server that previous row results are bad just mixed, bad part is only that previous row with SQL variables other query parts works good. Before it i thought, that problem is in sql variables part, but now i realized the problem is in "order by" keyword.

My query:

```
SELECT
   customers.title,
   calendar.start_time, 
   calendar.hours_per_time,
   calendar.self_certification,
   calendar.bulletin_certification,
   calendar.extra,
   DATE_FORMAT(calendar.date, '%d-%m') AS day_month,
   TIME_FORMAT(calendar.start_time, '%H:%i') AS hours_min,
   @previous_start AS previous_start,
   @previous_start := calendar.start_time,
   @previous_end AS previous_end,
   @previous_end := calendar.hours_per_time

        FROM
          (SELECT @previous_start := '00:00', @previous_end := '0.00') AS calendar_prev, calendar

            INNER JOIN relationships ON calendar.relation_id = relationships.relation_id
            INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = relationships.customer_id

            WHERE relationships.user_id = '$user_id'
            AND DATE_FORMAT(calendar.date, '%m-%Y') = '$date'

        ORDER BY calendar.date, hours_min ASC
```

If i remove hours_min from order by part everything works fine in both servers, but then i lose my ordering.

This is my result from development server green part is is from sql variables and here works fine:
[image]

And here is from production server with bad results in red part
[image]

So how can I keep my order and still have good results? Order is only needed by date(Dato) and hours_min(Fra kl.) columns.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the query as an inline view, and specify a different ORDER BY on the outer query.

As a simple demonstration of the pattern:

```
SELECT v.fee
     , v.fo
     , v.fi
  FROM ( 
         SELECT t.fee
              , t.fi 
              , t.fo
           JOIN t
          ORDER BY t.fi ASC, t.fo ASC
       ) v
 ORDER
    BY v.fee DESC
```

We can process rows "in order" in the query inside the inline view, using an `ORDER BY` clause on the inner `SELECT` statement.

The `ORDER BY` on the outer query can reorder the results returned by the inner query.

---

NOTES:

The MySQL Reference manual cautions that the behavior of user-defined variables that are set and read within the same statement is not guaranteed.  With that said, we do observe a consistent behavior.

It's an order of operations issue. That is, we are carefully constructing our SQL in such a way that MySQL execution plan gets us a predictable order of operations.

What we have discovered is that the ORDER BY is being processed before the expressions in the SELECT list are evaluated.

So, if we need to process rows "in order" such that the user defined variables contain values from the "previous" row when the expressions in the SELECT list are evaluated, then we need to have an ORDER BY that gets the rows in the desired order.

If we want the resulting rows in a different order, we need another ORDER BY operation to be processed later.  And we can get that using an inline view (what MySQL refers to as a "derived table"). That's because MySQL materializes that derived table "v" before the outer query is processed.

The SELECT list of the outer query can specify a different order of columns or omit columns. The order of expressions in the SELECT list of the inner query can be dictated by the order of operations required when working with the user-defined variables: the assignments that save the current row to the user-defined variables has to happen AFTER the user-defined variables are evaluated.

---

Also,  I would recommend ditching the comma syntax for the join operation, and replace that with the `JOIN` keyword.  The `CROSS` keyword is optional, but it does serve as an indication to the future reader that the omission of the `ON` clause is intentional, and not an oversight.

The `INNER` keyword is also optional; it has no effect, and my preference is to omit that.

```
 FROM (SELECT @previous_start := '00:00', @previous_end := '0.00') calendar_prev
CROSS
 JOIN calendar
 JOIN relationships 
   ON calendar.relation_id = relationships.relation_id
```

Comment: if I understood it properly, i just need to add ORDER BY into my sub query part? Like this: `FROM (SELECT @previous_start := '00:00', @previous_end := '0.00' ORDER BY hours_min)`, but then i get error `Unknown column 'hours_min' in 'order clause'` and that `JOIN t` is from where? which table i need to join here. I'm little bit confused please help me.

Comment: No, there's no ORDER BY required on the inline view that does the initlialization.. that returns one row, and we don't really care about the row it returns, we just care that it returns exactly one row (because it is being joined to other views/tables in the query). What we really care about is the initialization of the user-defined variables. That could actually be done as a separate SET statement, and omitted from the SELECT query; but I do prefer the pattern of doing it in the query.

Comment: What I was suggesting was that you wrap the query that is working inside parens, and then reference that in an outer query, and adding an ORDER BY on the outer query...  `SELECT v.* FROM ( <original query here> ) v ORDER BY v.whatever`.  The inline view query (the original query)  can also have an ORDER BY clause (inside the parens), and that can be different from the ORDER BY on the outer query.)

Comment: And again, the MySQL Reference Manual cautions that the behavior/results of a statement that both sets and reads user-defined variables is not guaranteed. To get this to work, the behavior we are after is to first get the rows ordered (either by index access, or by a Using filesort operation), and then processing the rows with the user-defined variables.  And we can get that behavior by causing MySQL to materialize an inline view (aka derived table).

Comment: An odd demonstration - as the inner one is redundant in this instance !?!

Answer (score -1):

Combining ORDER BY with variables in MariaDB is a bit tricky. Can you make a copy of the table already ordered by calendar.date, hours_min ASC and run the query on that copy without the ORDER BY?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."